# Form does not open in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tabs, target

this is the code I am using, I have specified target="_blank" in the form however it doesn't open in a new tab.

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="https://website.com/search/" + document.getElementById("url").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form action="https://website.com/search/" target="_blank" onSubmit="return process();">
Search: <input type="text" name="url" id="url"> <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Comment: When you return `false` from the function, the form doesn't get submitted, so the action and target are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` is only used when the form is submitted normmally. You're preventing this by returning `false` from the `onsubmit` function.

Since `process` is redirecting to a new URL instead of submitting the form, you can instead open a new window/tabl there. So replace

```
locaiton.href = url;
```

with:

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```